# What god(s) best embody my philosophy?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, alignment, religions-and-deities

I know that 'unaligned' is not a thing in 5th edition, but I am making a character who believes in the cycle of life and death, that no actions really change things and eventually all things succumb to time and return to the state they are meant to.

I want him to be neutral, but looking at the list of Forgotten Realms deities there are no gods with similar philosophies. The best I can find is Silvanus, but he is all about balancing sides, and my character believes that the sides will balance themselves in time, with no specific action needed, or maybe they won't balance, but they will do what they have to do and good / evil is pretty meaningless because nobody can say that good is any more 'correct' than evil (based on a probably flawed assumption of nihilism that I am not so bothered about correcting).

So, and I am happy to accept lore from older editions unless it is specifically changed in 5th edition, what (if any) god(s) (ideally from the Forgotten Realms) have this kind of philosophy?

Comment: This is probably not very imaginative of me but, if I was your DM, and you'd created 'a character who believes in the cycle of life and death, that no actions really change things' then I'd really appreciate you sending me a list of things that were motivational to your character and might hook them into the narrative. At first glance it's hard to see why they'd choose a life of adventure.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105621/discussion-on-question-by-seriousbri-what-gods-best-embody-my-philosophy).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some options from the D&D lore:

#### Philosophy / The Old Faith

First of all, your character's philosophy reminds me of the philosophies of two [Planescape factions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faction_(Planescape)): the Bleak Cabal and the Dustmen. After the Faction War, the members of these factions left Sigil, so you might consider being a character who (or whose ancestors) ended up on Toril. You do not need to worship any deities, but gain your powers directly from nature, as in the worship of the Old Faith. While the Old Faith originates from Oerth, it is defined in the *Player's Handbook* in a generic manner.

#### Moander

When you put nature and decay together, Moander would come to mind. While it was an evil power, it was known to lie for ages and it is easy to argue that it would support druids who are nihilistic. For example the boxed set *Netheril: Empire of Magic* states:

> Moander ... attracted the nihilists who saw all of existence as a constant decay toward death. ... Moander frequently lied, particularly when such prevarications caused great emotional distress in its victims.

If you want a major character arc, you could start playing as a misguided druid of Moander and gradually discover that it has been manipulating you. Another arc could be built on the fact that Moander was killed by Finder, and its vestige is trying to bring itself back.

#### Jergal

There is already an [excellent answer by NathanS](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166279/what-gods-best-embody-my-philosophy/166280#166280). Being an old deity of death who got bored, he would make a nice candidate in philosophical outlook. The only disadvantage is that he was never a deity whose portfolio included anything to do with nature.

Comment: Unless my DM says otherwise I am going with Moander, so have accepted this answer. The majority of the concept speaks to me, and I really love the idea of being mislead. I have decided to be implanted with a seed of Moander, follow the party because they are likely to lead me to more sources of death than I could otherwise see, and use a decompose cantrip to start the decay which will empower Moander and potentially allow his rebirth.

Answer (score 17):

### Try Jergal, previously the god of the dead, now the "scribe of the dead"

In *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*, p.30, and the sidebar on p. 31, describes how Jergal was the god of the dead, but basically got bored with the pointlessness of it all.

> Jergal ... was worshipped as the god of death, murder, and strife. Yet with the passing of time, he became bored with his position.
>
> [...]
>
> Jergal is now seen as an uncaring custodian of the dead. [...]
>
> – *Jergal, p.30, Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*

> Long ago there was but one god of strife, death, and the dead, and he was known as Jergal, Lord of the End of Everything. [...] As all things died, everything came to him eventually, and over time he built a kingdom unchallenged by any other god. But he grew tired of his duties, for he knew them too well, and without challenge there is nothing–and in nothingness there is only gloom. In such as state, the difference between absolute power and absolute powerlessness is undetectable.
>
> – *The Legend of Knucklebones, Skull Bowling, and the Empty Throne sidebar, p. 31, Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*

This sounds somewhat similar to the apathetic feel of the sort of god you're going for, although not quite the "everything balances out" side of things. However, that's the best I can find from Forgotten Realms lore.

Comment: I really like this, and unless a more nature and decay themed god (I am a druid after all) is found before the end of tomorrow will probably go with it!

Answer (score 4):

I really like the concept, because death doesn't have to be evil, which is where D&D tends to place gods of death.  [Death] from Neil Gaiman's *Sandman* series isn't evil, she is really part of life.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_(DC_Comics)#Fictional_character_biography)  I guess that we're stuck with the earthbound remnants of when ancient civilizations invented the mythological gods to explain the world.  They tended to have one for life and one for death.

On to your question, I do like **Silvanus**.  Nature is very much about the circle of life, renewal, etc.  Silvanus is the most Druid-y of Gods, and Druids are all about balance.

You could also split your devotion to both **Lathander**, god of birth and renewal, and to **Myrkul**, god of death.  I think your character could be free to be whatever alignment you choose and just ignore the gods' alignments.  Again, you could see the process as inherently Good or Evil, depending on how you look at it.  Lots of fantasy lore (probably starting with Tolkien) see the mortality of men as a blessing, as opposed to undying races.  IRL Christian theology places mankind in a special place with God, versus the immortal Heavenly Host [as a bonus, Host means Army].

Other options.  Savras, god of divination and fate plays to the inevitability of death. An elf of half-elf might choose **Rillifane Rallathil**, wood elf god of nature.  One might also see **Oghma**, god of knowledge, as representing the pursuit of knowledge and the understanding that life and death is the natural order.